# asp.net c# javascript The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using Asp.net c# with javascript 
I want use the Session value in javascript so am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Warehousename = '<%= Session["warehouse_id"] %>';
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = Warehousename.split(",");
    if (temp.length > 1) {
        alert('you have multiple access of warehouse. Kindly select the only one warehouse from Preference')
        window.location.href = "frm_preferences.aspx";
    }
</script>
```

But am facing some error like

> 'The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).'

So where am doing wrong please suggest me

Comment: Where is this code? in the head section?

Comment: Yes this code in head section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are possible solutions:

**First :**
Remove JavaScript from the header section of page and add it to body of the page and run your application it will work for you!

**Second :**

Replace the code block with `<%#` instead of `<%=`

After replace code block with `<%#` instead of `<%=` add following code in page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Page.Header.DataBind();    
}
```

Comment: thanks for great response. this solution works for script tags but not's working on link tags. do you know why?